# Spring Cloud Gateway Global Filter Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm not getting an output from my global filter (or any of my filters). I can verify that the bean for each filter is created at runtime, but I'm not sure why they aren't executed.

Dependencies:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.6.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-gateway 2.2.4
```

This is a global filter that I've created for testing purposes:

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered{
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        log.info("First Pre Global Filter");
        return chain.filter(exchange)
          .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
              log.info("Last Post Global Filter");
            }));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -1;
    }
    
}
```

Routes config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: microservice
        uri: lb://microservice
        predicates:
        - Path=/microservice/**
...
```

I've also tried setting up another spring cloud gateway with the filter above and it works, so there's definitely nothing wrong with the filter. Any idea what might be the cause of my issue? Or how do I troubleshoot it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with my `WebClient`. I did not access the microservice through the gateway but instead, it directly accesses the microservice. Hence, the filters did not run as the request did not go through the routes.

Original:

```
webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://microservice").build();
```

Fixed:

```
webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/microservice").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way :

```js
@Component
@Order(-1)
public class TestFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        log.info("First Pre Global Filter");
        return chain.filter(exchange)
            .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        log.info("Last Post Global Filter");
    }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. Apparently the there's no issue with the filters and the routes. The issue is that my webclient directly accesses the URI instead of going through the gateway. I'll post more about it in another answer.